# Validate duplicates in a angular reactive form

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example

I click on the add credentials 3 times and get 3 elements for username and password.

In the first row i enter username as Jhon and password as smith.

In the second row when i enter the name John in the username field and tab to the password field .I want the input field to become red.

Any ideas how i go about firing an event and what event should be fired ?
whenever i touch the input element

enter a duplicate value

and lose focus on it

I am clueless how i achieve this.

Comment: Yes, you can create your own Validator.
And check if the username\password what ever you want is the same return error.

Also BIG NOTICE: YOU CANT USE THE SAME formControlName
for all of your inputs.
your gonna need to do something like this username1\password1 username2\password2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onblur` event will work.

html:

```
<input (blur)="onBlur($event)" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
```

ts:

```
...
onBlur($event) {
  // compare form.values
}
...
```

But something's wrong with that stackblitz example. input field got blurred immediately after typing.